# Adicionar campo ao formulário de registro padrão do laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde,

quero adicionar o campo type para o usuário de um sistema em laravel e estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

**migration**

```
   public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->string('email')->unique();
         $table->string('password');
         $table->smallInteger('type');
         $table->rememberToken();
         $table->timestamps();
     });
    }
```

**register.blade.php (acrescentei um select para type):**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tipo de usuário: </label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="type" style="width:350px">
      <option value="1">Cliente</option>
      <option value="2">Funcionário</option>
      <option value="3">Gerente</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

**RegisterController:**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'type' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'type' => $data['type'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

O usuário é salvo mas sempre com o tipo 0 e não entendi o porquê disso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esta nos fillables do seu Model User, aconselho duas mudanças:

1 - Melhorar o migration para ter um valor default no type.

```
   public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->string('email')->unique();
         $table->string('password');
         $table->smallInteger('type')->default(1);
         $table->rememberToken();
         $table->timestamps();
     });
    }
```

2 - É necessário rever seu model, que deve ter o atributo fillable com todas as colunas do banco.

```
 protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'type'];
```

Assim as funções create, update e métodos afins, devem funcionar perfeitamente.